# Air for iOS Sound Fades Away When Home Button Is Pressed

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I am having trouble getting a sound to play in the background when the app isn't active. Whenever I press the home button the sound quickly fades out and when I navigate back to the app is fades back in.

I have updated my index-app.xml file to allow the audio background mode:

```
<iPhone>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>standard</requestedDisplayResolution>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[<key>UIDeviceFamily</key><array><string>2</string></array>    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key><array><string>audio</string></array>]]></InfoAdditions>
</iPhone>
```

I have also set:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.executeInBackground = true;
```

then my sound code is pretty simple:

```
sound = new Sound();
sound.load(new URLRequest("media/default/song.mp3"));
channel = sound.play(0);
```

I have been through the documentation up and down and can't seem to figure out why the song refuses to play in the background when the app isn't active. Any help would be swell! THanks!!

Comment: Try this : https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Background-Music

Answer (score 0):

A quick stab in the dark. Are you using direct mode in the AIR settings? Direct mode doesn't allow background execution in iOS until AIR 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update yuor application.XML to support background sounds.

```
<InfoAdditions> 
    <![CDATA[ 
       <key>UIBackgroundModes</key> 
           <array> 
               <string>audio</string> 
            </array> 
    ]]> 
</InfoAdditions>
```

here's the Adobe docs on that.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f7e64a7f12cd2dd1867-8000.html#WSd6d4f896b3a8801b-15a1d5f91370ecb9970-8000